# How much Base Proof is required?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, induction, conjectures

If I were looking to use the Theory of Strong Induction, to prove the statement that:

> The Set of All Even Numbers is equal to the Set of All Odd Numbers multiplied by $2^n$, where $n \geq 1$

$$
\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{O} \cdot \{2^n \mid n \geq 1 \} 
$$

How much Base Proof would be required to show or infer that it is true?

1. $2 = 1 \cdot 2^1$
2. $4 = 1 \cdot 2^2$
3. $6 = 3 \cdot 2^1$
4. $8 = 1 \cdot 2^4$
5. $10 = 5 \cdot 2^1 \dots$

I get that for Strong Induction you have to show all the base proofs up to a certain point. But in this case, what would that minimum requirement be? Is there a minimum amount required, or is this what makes a Conjecture? Because the base proof requires an infinite number of base proofs, to prove the statement and relies more on a formula for its proof over Strong Induction?

Comment: You mean $\Bbb E=\bigcup_{n\ge0}2^n\Bbb O$. Anyway, this only works if you don't count $0$ in $\Bbb E$, which is why my answer assumes $\Bbb E,\,\Bbb O$ have positive elements only.

Comment: I do apologize for any confusion my question may have caused, but it seems you understood what I was trying to convey/ask.
Thank you for correcting my formulas, I tried my best when writing it, but I'm still new to all of this and I realize I'm going to make mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to prove by strong induction all integers $m\ge1$ are of the form $2^n(2a+1)$ for integers $a,\,n\ge0$. The following statement of the principle of strong induction is sufficient:

> Let $P$ denote a predicate of positive integers. If $\forall k<m(P(m))\implies P(m)$, then $\forall m(P(m))$.

*There is no base case*. Clearly $P(1)$ because $\forall k<1(P(k))$ is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) ($0$ "doesn't exist" from the perspective of quantification over *positive* integers). Since $P(1)$, $\forall k<2(P(k))$, so $P(2)$, and so on.

The hard part is proving $\forall k<m(P(k))\implies P(m)$. Your proof of that might require considering small values of $m$ especially, but that's up to you to find out for whichever $P$ concerns you.

Comment: And if my concern is the infinite nature of the Even and Odd Sets? I'm looking to possibly use this ?concept? in a proof for a different project, and that project deals with the infinite set of all natural positive integers. My thought process was if I could show that half of all natural positive integers (The Set of All Odd Numbers) effectively can be shown to have an Even Number Element partner, thus reducing the proofs I need down to just the Set of All Positive Even Numbers. 

Or am I chasing a pipe dream with this direction of thought?

Comment: @HoushouRattengod I _think_ I understand what you mean. So is your aim to prove something is true of all positive integers by first checking the odd ones (the case $n=0$), then showing if $m$ works so does $2m$? If so, you only need _weak_ induction, to increase $n$ by $1$; but checking odds will be weak induction's $n=0$ base step.

Comment: Basically. But I realized quickly that just $2m$ wasn't enough, because it doesn't cover all elements of the Even Set. An easy example is the number 12. which is $6(2)$ but it is also $3(2^2)$. Seeing that, I did a quick sheet and was able to count (by 2's) from 2 to 50. Just by using whatever you wanna call the method above.
I have a few other things I need to work out for the project I'm working on. But part of the proof I'm working on has basis in this concept. And you're saying that I only need Weak Induction for it to work, yes?

Comment: @HoushouRattengod Whatever your example is may be worth asking a fresh question about in case you're stuck on either its base step or its inductive step, but _if_ the $m$ to $2m$ inference works _regardless of the value of $m$_, we do indeed need only weak induction. For example, we go from $3$ to $6$, from $6$ to $12$ etc.